# Robots.txt "Allow" command?

Tags: search-engine, robots.txt

In my robots.txt:

```
Disallow: /account
Allow: /account/
```

In my site, there is a page at `/account` which would only be accessible to someone logged in, but then to see the profile page of another user, you would go to `/account/username`. So I want robots.txt to disallow the single `/account` page but allow the directory. Does this setup work?

Corollary: Does `Disallow: /account` also disallow the directory `/account/` or am I just wasting my time by then explicitly allowing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things to watch out for here.

First, as @plasticinsect said in his answer, the most specific rule wins. For GoogleBot. Other bots, though, use the rule from the original robots.txt protocol that says directives are processed in sequential order--the order they appear in the robots.txt file. Those bots would see the Disallow and stop.

At minimum, you should swap the order of the Allow and Disallow.

In addition, there is sometimes disagreement about whether `/account` and `/account/` are different urls. If a crawler hits your site with `http://example.com/account/`, the robots.txt is going to allow it. You probably want to disallow `/account/$`. That won't stop *all* bots (those that don't support the `$` end-of-string marker will ignore the directive), but it's worth a shot.

Given that, I would suggest:

```
Disallow: /account/$
Allow: /account/
Disallow: /account
```

Or, if you're just worried about Googlebot and other major crawlers:

```
Disallow: /account$
Disallow: /account/$
```

Answer (score 2):

For Googlebot, this will definitely work. For other web robots, it may or may not, depending on how they implement robots.txt. I wouldn't count on it.

According to: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt,

"At a group-member level, in particular for allow and disallow directives, the most specific rule based on the length of the [path] entry will trump the less specific (shorter) rule."

Since '/account/' is longer than '/account' the allow will override the disallow, at least on Googlebot.

This will almost certainly NOT work on many other web robots, however. The original robots.txt standard does not even include the Allow directive. Even if a robot does support Allow, there is no guarantee it prioritizes the same way as Google. So, if you only really care about Google, go for it. If you need this to work for other robots, you might want to find a different solution, maybe robots meta tags or the X-Robots-Tag header.

To answer your related question, "Disallow: /account" will block any file or path that starts with "/account", including "/account/user", so yes, you do need the allow.